# How can I make the size of the PDF equal to the of the chessboard?

Tags: margins, preview

I have this piece of LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}
% Source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15278/5645

\usepackage{chessboard}
\storechessboardstyle{4x4}{maxfield=d4}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}

% showmover shows which player is to move
\chessboard[style=4x4,setwhite={Qa1,Qd2},showmover=false]

\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

And I compile using pdflatex.

But the PDF document is too wide (just mark the image to see its width)

[image: chess board - too wide]

**How can I make the width of the PDF equal to the of the chessboard?**

Comment: You could also remove the extra whitespace in a separate step using `pdfcrop`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is the blank lines in the preview environment. You'll get a tight box by removing them:

```
\begin{preview}
% showmover shows which player is to move
\chessboard[style=4x4,setwhite={Qa1,Qd2},showmover=false]
\end{preview}
```

See also [Standalone package creates a page with a fixed width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34590/627)

Comment: The blank lines create a paragraph, so the output is `\linewidth` wide. Removing the lines will give you only an horizontal box with no added space.

Answer (score 4):

### Case 1

`standalone` has an option `border` that you can use to specify the left, bottom, right, top borders. Negative values can also be used to trim.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border={-8pt -8pt -18pt -18pt}]{standalone}
% Source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15278/5645

\usepackage{chessboard}
\storechessboardstyle{4x4}{maxfield=d4}

\begin{document}
% showmover shows which player is to move
\chessboard[style=4x4,setwhite={Qa1,Qd2},showmover=false]
\end{document}
```

### Case 2

If you want to have equal borders or trimmed offset, just use one value `border=-5pt` for example.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=-5pt]{standalone}
% Source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15278/5645

\usepackage{chessboard}
\storechessboardstyle{4x4}{maxfield=d4}

\begin{document}
% showmover shows which player is to move
\chessboard[style=4x4,setwhite={Qa1,Qd2},showmover=false]
\end{document}
```

Remarks: The red rectangles were added when I converted the PDF output to PNG. They are useful to show the edges of the outputs.