# Draw colored tiles

Tags: chess

How can I produce squares like this of arbritary sizes?
[image: colored squares]

I have been looking at skak, but cannot find an example that is not producing entire chessboards.

I know I have seen this somewhere before, but I cannot remember the words that describe this in english.

Comment: Maybe this question helps you?
http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15275/41356

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using something specific to chess I would use [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/skak) rather than [skak](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/skak). The basic idea of [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/skak) is to use `\draw` commands with xy-coordinates. Here is one way to produce shaded 2x2 squares:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% \BackSquares{ list of south west coordinates of squares to fill }
\newcommand\BlackSquares[1]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[ultra thick](0,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \draw[ultra thick](0,1)--(2,1);
    \draw[ultra thick](1,0)--(1,2);
    \foreach \sq in {#1} {\draw[fill=black]\sq rectangle ++(1,1);}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
  \BlackSquares{{(0,0)},{(1,0)}}
  \BlackSquares{{(0,0)},{(0,1)}}
  \BlackSquares{{(0,0)},{(1,1)}}
  \BlackSquares{{(1,0)},{(0,1)}}
\end{document}
```

This MWE produces:[image]

Comment: Great, thank you. I just always struggle when it comes to tikz and it ends up with trial and error. but that looks pretty simple too me